# Boostrap Model error with bootstrap.js file

Tags: javascript

Recently i face a problem with `bootstrap.js` `bootstrap.min.js` file when I include this files than my model is not working and when I remove this files than my `bootstrap` model works fine

Can any body tell me what actually happen ?

```
<script src="<?php echo $js; ?>bootstrap.js" > </script>

<script src="<?php echo $js; ?>bootstrap.min.js" > </script>
```

I include it in `init.php,  if I remove both JS files from my`init.php` file than it affects whole site please help me out what I have to do now ?

Comment: delete one bootstarp file and check.. one is minimized version.. so you have to use only one

Comment: Thanks bro but it works   when i remove both files ...

Comment: check your code if any other bootstrap js r you using or not ? and show me link or paste your whole code here

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: Ohh Yes Brother problem is solved thanks a lot . i detect that i used TWO boostrap.min.js file  i removed both and my page is now working. my problem is solved Thank You !

Comment: please upvoted  answer @Mr1125 i ahve given below answer

Comment: how bro i am newbie .. tell me how can i give vote ?

Answer (score 0):

delete one bootstarp file and check.. one is minimized version.. so you have to use only one